# Django - visualising code execution flow

Tags: python, django, diagram

Is it possible to visualize how the code is executed?

I have an ajax call to the server and what I would like to get is some sort of diagram or detailed report which will have information containing which functions were called etc.

Answer (score 0):

In pycharm you can run your script in profile mode http://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2015/05/pycharm-4-5-eap-build-141-988-introducing-python-profiler/